# Mocha does not catch undeclared variable

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am fairly new to using mocha and I ran into this bug. Please help me understand this behavior.

```
'use strict';
 var flightMiddlewareMock = require(process.cwd() + '/test/mock/response/flightmock');


describe('Test Flights function: getTime', function(){
  var mockData;
  beforeEach(function(done){
    mockData = flightMiddlewareMock.getValidData();
    done();
  }
  it('getFlightDescription returns the full flight description', function(done){

    contentUtils.loadContent({
            'files': {
                activity: '/flights/america'
            },
            'locality': "en_US"
    }, function(err, bundle) {

            var flightsMiddleware = new FlightsMiddleware(country, mockData.req, bundle); 
            console.log('inside content callback');

            description = flightsMiddleware.getFlightDescription(mockData.results.body.items[0]);

            assert.equal(description, "Boeing 777");
            done();
    }
  });
});
```

Output looks like this

```
inside content callback
inside content callback
inside content callback
```

- Failure of test!

Question - I do not understand why in spite of using 'use strict' it does not complain about description not being declared.

Please note: If I do modify this to

```
var description = .....
```

it works viola! Am I missing something? 
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocha will report the exception caused by trying to assign to an undeclared variable. If I run this:

```
"use strict";

it("foo", function (done) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        description = "foo";
        done();
    }, 1000);
});
```

I get the result:

```
  1) foo

  0 passing (1s)
  1 failing

  1)  foo:
     Uncaught ReferenceError: description is not defined
      at null._onTimeout (test.js:5:21)
```

Now, I've used `setTimeout` which is a well-behaved function in that when the callback passed to it throws an exception, `setTimeout` does not prevent this exception from reaching the top of execution context. In other words, it does not swallow exceptions.

If you have a callback that throws an exception but *this exception is swallowed by the code that called the callback*, you'll get a test timeout but you won't know why because Mocha won't be able to detect the exception. It relies on the [`uncaughtException` event](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception), which is not emitted if the exception is swallowed.

Comment: I understand that the callback swallows the event. But I do not understand why is "inside content callback" displayed thrice? why does it keep going back?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of `contentUtils.loadContent`, which you do not show. If the callback is called multiple times, for instance, then you'll get multiple outputs to the console.